# getting error while uploading image using video.upload

Tags: facebook

error- This method must run on api-video.facebook.com

here is my code

`[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"Video.upload" params:params dataParam:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"creme.mov"]];`

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking, use facebook.video.upload instead of video.upload.
It'll map it under water to the proper server.